# Extract raster value into polygon

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, qgis-processing, zonal-statistics

I have the raster map of monthly precipitation of some years (download from CGIAR http://www.cgiar-csi.org/data/uea-cru-ts-v3-10-01-historic-climate-database) and I need the mean values on a specific area (polygonal shapefile). I tried with zonal statistic but I had not results, the attribute table was empty.

Is it possible that my region is too small for do this?

I'm a bit new in QGIS world.

Answer (score 6):

Before using `Zonal Statistics` make sure that you have same projections for both raster data and vector (shapefile) data. Sometimes different projection produce empty results. In the following example, I used WGS 84 for both raster data (SRTM Global) and a polygon vector data (Test.shp), and I didn't specify any column prefix:

[image]

The final output is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. convert raster to vector using (https://online.rapidresizer.com/tracer.php)
2. Run this python tool:

---

```py
import arcpy
import xlwt
import os
outfile = "C:\Users\soft\Desktop\Pole\exce\Domain_Description_report.xls"
try:
    if os.path.exists(outfile):
        os.remove(outfile)
except OSError:
    print 'Unable to delete Report File at '+outfile
    quit()
book = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet1 = book.add_sheet("Featureclass_coordinates")
cntx1 = 1
#cnty2=1
input_fc="C:\Users\soft\Desktop\Pole\Pole.shp"
sheet1.write(0,0,"Feature Id")
sheet1.write(0,1,"Coordinates")
sheet1.write(0,2,"POLETYPE")
desc = arcpy.Describe(input_fc)
if desc.shapeType.upper()=="POINT":
    for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(input_fc, ["OID@", "SHAPE@XY","POLETYPE"]):    
        x,y = row[1]
        if x!=None:
            #print(cntx1)
            sheet1.write(cntx1, 0,"Feature "+str(row[0]))
            sheet1.write(cntx1, 1,"{}, {}".format(x, y))
            sheet1.write(cntx1, 2,"{}".format(row[2]))
            cntx1= cntx1 + 1
else:
    print("Loaded Shape file is not a polygon")
book.save(outfile)
```

Comment: Side note you have to own esri software to use arcpy